# How to setup Maven to enable JSF2 resources versioning?

Tags: maven, jsf-2

I have read the following essay:
[Resources (library) in JSF 2.0](https://mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/)

It's about versioning of web resources for JSF2 project.

May I know how could I do when my project is Maven-based? What need to be setup or added in the Maven setting?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I vote to reopen since I think it is about e.g. automagically adding a maven version info into the resources folder structure. Effective;y being a combination of two questions. One of which is the duplicate and one is some maven resources copy/move action with placeholders

Comment: I'll try to write an answer over the weekend when I have access to a normal pc again instead of just s mobile phone

Comment: @Kukeltje any update? Thank you.

Comment: And in your new question, post the complete structure of the resouces folder hierarchy and how you use it in a [mcve]. Yes, the output is relevant to, but also the server side source. And in the new question, also take https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472095/jsf-is-unable-to-find-resources-in-sub-folders into account

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143383/how-to-use-jsf-versioning-for-resources-in-jar too (are your resources in a separate jar or not?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively your question is a combination of three existing questions in Stackoverflow.

One is already superfluous since you already know how JSF versioning works, you just (unfortunately) referred an external site and not the [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) but from this question you need to 'remember' the format of the version number that needs to be used.

The second part should also not have been to difficult to come up with. JSF is a runtime framework and has no build/deploy time features. But you already use maven, so what is needed to **build time** [copy(move?) the resources to a new location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851915/how-can-i-copy-an-entire-directory-into-another-directory-using-maven). The source folder can differ, it can be an additional resources folder e.g. src/main/myresources, that you don't treat as a resources (since it would end up in the classes folder then by default) or it can be a folder inside the webcontent and then you need to move (copy/delete). This is all for you to find out.

The third part is that the destination folder needs the version in the right format

```
1_0
1_1
1_2_3
```

Since this differs from the project version format, you need to search/replace this
which includes the project version **in the right format**. There are [features for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347796/manipulate-project-version-property-to-remove-snapshot) as well in maven.

So you see, it all boils down to breaking a problem down into manageable parts...

Comment: I have deployed versioning successfully. It can adapt the highest-level version resources. However, in html, it doesn't show the link like ".../javax.faces.resource/css/style.css?ln=default&amp;v=2_0" but just ".../javax.faces.resource/css/style.css?ln=default". How can I enable it to show the version number?

Comment: Great! Maybe you can share the important parts in an additional answer? Regarding the version info missing in the link, I do not really have an idea. Please create a new question for this and we'll see if we can get to the bottom of this (or find a duplicate).

Comment: I have update the question and see if you can understand it more.

Comment: I said **new** question... Not edit the existing one ;-)

Comment: my question quota reached limit

Comment: anyway my problem solved :) I wrote a custom resourceHandler to solve my issue. Thanks a lot.